# Transform a region of $\mathbb{R}$ into a unit square.

Tags: calculus

Consider the region R bounded by the curves $y=-x^2$, $y=x$ and $x=1$. I would like to transform this region to $S=\{ (u,v) | 0\le u \le 1, 0 \le v \le 1 \}$ using some transformation $x=x(u,v)$ and $y=y(u,v)$? 
I am not able to find such a transformation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the region $R$? I plotted the three conditions here: https://imgur.com/a/CeF4e0d .

Comment: Hint: Look for a way to map $[-x^2,x]$ onto $[0,1]$. The transformation might end up being undefined at the origin, but if your ultimate goal is to integrate over $R$ that might not matter.

Comment: @WarreG you have plotted $y=1$ instead of $x=1$.

Comment: Oh wow how embarrassing. You could split up the regions in two parts : the triangle and then the region above $y = -x^2$ for $x : 0 \rightarrow 1$. $x$ will go from 0 to one so $y$ from 0 to $-1$.  If you can find a transformation that mirrors $-x^2$ on $x^2$ it's done I think.